# Xml schema regex to not allow white spaces alone

Tags: regex, xml, xsd

In xml, i have a tag say `<membercode>`

The regex pattern for the field currently is  `<xs:pattern value="[a-zA-Z0-9\s]{1,3}" />`

The membercode  must accept values as follows:

```
1) "XY"  -> pass

2) "XY " -> pass

3) "   " -> i need to have this failed. but it is getting passed.

4) " XY " -> need to be failed
```

EDIT: Requirements:

1) total allowed characters must be maximum 3.

2) With in the allowed 3 chars, there can be spaces. ex: `"XY", "XY "," XY" , "X "`

3) But if the total chars exceed 3 or if there is only spaces(no alphanumeric chars) then it should not be allowed.

tried  whitespace collapse property, but in that case the maxlength is applied after the collapse is done.
so values more than max length is also allowed.

hence tried below things..

```
<xs:pattern value="[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,3}[\s?]" />
<xs:pattern value="[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,3}|[a-zA-Z0-9\s?]{1,3}" />
```

but couldn't get hold on the correct solution.

Please point me the correct approach for this..

Many thanks for the suggestions!

Comment: I think it would be better if you tell us the requirements (it needs one to three letters to be ok, it can have optional spaces at the end, etc) instead of just the examples.

Comment: edited the question with requirements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're on the right track using `<xs:whiteSpace>` restriction, but the value should be `preserve` in order to not modify the original whitespace.

You can use **this pattern**:

```
[\w\d ]*[\w\d][\w\d ]*
```

The central part (`[\w\d]`) says that **a letter or a digit must appear**. Before and after that compulsory alphanumeric character, the string can optionally have any letter/digit/space combination (`[\w\d ]*`). The restrictions `<xs:whiteSpace>` and `<xs:maxLength>` ensure that there is no more than 3 length strings including original white-spaces.

```
<xs:element name="elem">
    <xs:simpleType>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:whiteSpace value="preserve"/>
            <xs:maxLength value="3"/>
            <xs:pattern value="[\w\d ]*[\w\d][\w\d ]*"></xs:pattern>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
</xs:element>
```

Note that you can change `\w` to `a-zA-Z` if you don't want the underscore character that is also included in `\w`.

Answer (score 2):

<strike>This should work:</strike>

```
[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\s]{1,2}

[\w\d][\w\d\s]{1,2} equivalent
```

Does this help you out?

```
\s?[\w\d]{1,3}\s?
```

Comment: "  Y" (with 2 spaces) is not passed.

Comment: `\s?[\w\d]{1,3}\s?` works..but fails for case " XY " ; since total chars is 4 in this case.

Comment: Could you clarify your requirements a bit more? Is there a character limit including spaces? Does " XY " need to be accepted or not?

Comment: total allowed characters must be maximum 3. With in the allowed 3 chars, there can be spaces. ex: `"XY", "XY "," XY" , "X  " ` are valid. But if the total chars exceed 3 or if there is only spaces(no alphanumeric chars) then it should not be allowed. `" XY "` must not be allowed since total chars is 4.

Comment: I'm not quite sure but can't you add: 
    `<xs:maxLength value="3"/>`